# Spring Framework. Сигнатура сервисных методов

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Насколько мне известно, методы сервиса должны принимать и возвращать DTO. Получается, что в контроллере при вызове методов из сервиса иногда мне приходится писать что-то вроде примеров 1,2

```
messageService.findByRoomAndUser(RoomDTO.forId(16),UserDTO.forId(10));//1
messageService.findByRoomAndUser(roomDTO,userDTO);//2
messageService.findByRoomAndUser(16,10);//3
messageService.findByRoomAndUser(roomDTO.getId(),userDTO.getId());//4
```

В 1 примере сложнее перепутать местами параметры, что плюс.
Стоит ли создавать новые обьекты как в примере 1 чтобы не писать код вроде:

```
MessageDTO findByRoomAndUser(RoomDTO room, UserDTO user) {
return findByRoomAndUser(room.getId(),user.getId());
}
MessageDTO findByRoomAndUser(Long roomId, Long userId) {
//код функции
}
```

Или все-же делать методы, которым нужен только идентификатор, согласно примеру 3, а при их вызове для объектов использовать `getId()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте сделал разделение:
1. `RoomDTO findByRoom(id)` и
2. `UserDTO findByUser(id)`,
а после найденных `RoomDTO` и `UserDTO` передать, например, в конструктор -
 `return new MessageDTO(room, user)`